# generating an html attachment vb.net

Tags: vb.net, report, system.net.mail

I am trying to generate a report html file and email it as an attachment with vb.net
I know how send mail and attachments.

Do I need to generate the html file, save it as an .html file to the local disk where the program runs, then add its file path to the attachment property to send it to the recipient?

It is going to be a rather large report, and I would like to send it as an attachment instead of directly inside of the email itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you save the file to disk ant then add to the Attactments collection of the MailMessage.  Here is the C# syntax to create an Attachment from a file on disk and add the attachment to the message.  It will be similar for VB.Net.

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(filename);
message.Attachments.Add(att);
```

Comment: yeah it is basically the same thing -- thanks I just wanted sure if i had to save it first or not, appreciate it

Comment: @Jeff - Attachment also accept a MemoryStream, so that is an option if you do not want to save to disk.

Comment: ^^- what I was looking for, I was trying to avoid saving it to the local disk.